# Own very small CMS viable?

Tags: web, web-applications, content-management-system

I currently have a website which is almost finished. The friend I am developing this website for now said that a blog would be cool but it is just a small additional feature; the main focus of the website is something entirely else. As he does not know HTML or CSS, I figured it would be best to provide him with a small tool to post new blog entries etc. which is essentially a very small CMS.

Do you think it's viable to create this myself or should I rather learn a real CMS and integrate it with the website? I've read online that creating a custom tool is almost always a bad idea, but I think that in this case it'd be faster than redeveloping the whole website for a specific CMS as I would also have to learn that specific CMS (I know none so far).

So I'd basically create a Go webserver for the website that also offers an admin functionality where my friend can enter details of a blog post and the server will manage it using the Go templates library.

Do you think this is a good idea or would you recommend something else for my situation? I just need a small tool for my friend to update his blog and I'd rather not spend too much time on adapting the website for a specific CMS.

Comment: If you don't have to create it on your own, why should you? Instead of using a whole CMS, why not use something smaller, like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) or [Ghost](https://ghost.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies - first post - so I may have strayed! I can't give you a definitive yes/no answer but I can provide a few strong pointers. It depends on where you want this and subsequent web-sites to go. We home-brewed up and ran a CMS for a number of years, then purchased one, then a few years later realised that this purchased CMS was not keeping up with technology. Consequently we went back to in-house but this time the set up was much harder. We were much more appreciative of the amount of "back-plane" supplied by a decent CMS. So, do set up the blog up as a stand-alone module so you appreciate how messy an apparently simple use-case like a blog is in terms of role-management, sharing, authentication, change-control, expiry etc. When you've done that, you'll have seen some of at what a CMS offers and be able to select a tool much more critically. I also noted the phrase "would be cool" - this is a classic scope-creep phrase - it may be that the web-site will be having a few more additions in the near future! You may be grateful for going with a CMS at that point.